# Wordpress if post has an image I want to display that image if doesn't (do nothing)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

In my wordpress theme I use  function to display the first image of the post in my index.php

for me, I don't want to add support thumbnails in my theme. its so annoying!

I watched an tutorial that teach how to display images in the left beside the the excerpt of the post by adding a padding-left for the excerpt and floating the image to the left so that the image is in the left and the excerpt is beside the image. Also, the tutorial teach you how to do nothing when there's no image for the post (to do nothing=to not push the excerpt and to not add floating to the image so the format of the post look normal).

He did this by using the fucntion if has_post_thumbnail = do something (add a padding-left to the excerpt and float image to the right) and if the post doesn't have thumbnail = do nothing. that's it.

Here's the code:

```
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>has-thumbnail <?php } ?>">

        <!-- post-thumbnail -->
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></a>
        </div><!-- /post-thumbnail -->



        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>">
```

Now I want to do the same but I don't want add support for thumbnails in my theme and i'm not planning to support thumbnails.

I tried to replace has_post_thumbnail() with the function I use get post first image but it didn't work.

I really need to do this in my website. So, is there's any solution guys?

Comment: Hacking to avoid using post thumbnails is going to be more work than just enabling them in the first place (which involves adding a single line to *functions.php*)

Answer (score 1):

You should **really** consider using featured images. It only takes adding a single line to *functions.php* to enable them...

However, if you still don't want to, you can check for image attachments to posts using the following:

```
// Get images attached to the current post
$images = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

// If there are images
if ( $images ) {
    // Show stuff 
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have work it out myself using catch that image function

Answer (score 0):

`the_post_thumbnail` calls the featured image... which is what you supposedly don't want to do.

Instead, you need to check the post contents for an image. There's answers here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60245/get-first-image-in-a-post

Comment: I have already tried to replace has_post_thumbnail with the function catch_that_image() and it didn't work!

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have work it out myself using catch that image function

Answer (score 0):

Use `has_post_thumbnail()` conditional function. See [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail).

But if you really don't want to use post thumbnails (you should, but you're the boss), [see this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143644/get-id-of-first-image-attached-to-a-post).

Comment: I don't support thumbnails in my theme. Read my question again pls.

Comment: You asked for solution - the PROPER solution is adding post thumbnail support. They are exactly for this case. Anyway, if you still don't want to use post thumbnails, see my updated answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have work it out myself using catch that image function

Comment: Are you aware `catch_that_image()` isn't a standard WP function? :)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of this, someone made this great function. It's helpful